# Prove mathematically

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Q.1   Consider the dual simplex method applied to a standard form problem with linearly independent rows. Suppose we have a basis which is primal infeasible, but dual feasible, and let i be such that xB(i) < 0. Suppose that all the entries in the ith row in the tableau other than this entry are non negative. Then, the dual LP has an improving recession direction.

```
                 min   cx

                 s.t.    Ax = b
                   x non-negative.
```

Q.2 For the above standard form LP, if there exists a w (1xm) such that c+wA >= 0, then the LP has a bounded optimal value.

Comment: For first part i know that if i am able to show the two condition that my WA<0 and Wb>0 than there exits a recession direction in dual and my dual will be unbounded.

Comment: i have a problem in second question for this  LP that how i can show?